# The type 'bool' is not compatible with the type 'IDisposable'

Tags: f#, idisposable

I am just new to F# programming and I am building a project which contains a F# file and during build there is an error in line 5(progress):

---

> The type 'bool' is not compatible with the type 'IDisposable'

---

```
   member private this.Main() = async{
        let! cont = async{
            try
                let! model = async{
   (*Error*)        use! progress = Progress.Show(ctx, LocalDevice.instance.loading)
                    return! load()
                }
                return this.ShowForm(model)
            with err -> 
                do! show_error(err)
                return this.Main()
        }
        return! cont
    }
```

**Does anyone know why this error is coming and what is the solution?**

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No-one here is willing to read your entire source-code.

Comment: boolean variable does not support IDisposable. Only objects that implements IDisposable interface can be used with "use" keyword

Comment: Take a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/resource-management-the-use-keyword

Comment: What's the return type of `Show`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann return type of Show is bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `use` (or `use!`) something that's `IDisposable`, which `bool` isn't (as the compiler error states). Use `let!` instead:

```
let! progress = Progress.Show(ctx, LocalDevice.instance.loading)
```